# about pairwise non commuting elements in a special p-groups

Tags: group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups

I will be so thankful for any answer of the following question by proof or by computer.

Suppose $G$ is an Extra-special group of order $3^5$ what is the maximum number of pairwise non-commuting elements in this group? Martin Isaacs has proved the  maximum number of pairwise elements in Extra-special 2-group of order $2^{2n+1}$ is $2n+1$.

By Extra-special group I mean the group $G$ of order $p^{2n+1}$ for some prime $p$ which its center is equal to its commutator and is of order $p$. In addition every non-central elements has conjugacy class of order $p$.

Comment: It boils down to a simple linear algebra problem: in a symplectic vector space over $F_3$ of dimension 4, what is the maximal cardinal of a subset in which every 2 distinct elements have nonzero symplectic product.

Comment: An you can choose the first two vectors in your set to be any two vectors with nonzero symplectic product.

Comment: @YCor, I could not understand your explanation. Is it possible to say the maximun size of this subset.

Comment: I'd be happy to help more, but in MathSE rather than here. This is not research-level.

Comment: My computer says that the answer is 7 and is realised uniquely up to isomorphism (in the non-commuting graph).

Comment: I also did a quick computer calculation and got the answer $7$.

Comment: In the following paper the author has found an upper and lower bound for extraspecial p-groups where p is odd.   A. Y. M. Chin, On non-commuting sets in an extraspecial p-group, J. Group Theory, 8 no. 2 (2005) 189-194.

Comment: I have not found any new result about the exact size of the above subset. So I thought it is a research problem.

Comment: I would say that the general problem is a research problem, but you asked about a single specific case, which can be solved very quickly and easily by computer. I think that if you want to do research in finite group theory, then you need to learn to use a computer system, such as GAP or Sage or Magma, yourself, so that you can at least solve routine problems, and not expect other people to do them for you.  There is a GAP forum, so you could ask for help there.

Comment: This is a problem in  finite projective geometry. 
The key words are minimal blocking sets and ovoids.
See 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovoid_(projective_geometry)      I have put it as an answer as I think the problem is not group theory, of course when one correctly understands how to convert it to a Finite projective geomerty problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's of any use, here is some (badly formatted) Magma code for this calculation, which works by converting it into a maximal clique computation in a graph on $80$ vertices.

```
> G := ExtraSpecialGroup(3,2);
> Q,phi := quo<G | Centre(G) >;
> V := [q : q in Q | q ne Id(Q)];
> E := {@ @};
> for i in [1..79] do for j in [i+1..80] do
> if (V[i]@@phi, V[j]@@phi) ne Id(G) then Include(~E, {i,j});
> end if; end for; end for;
> Gr := Graph< 80 | E >;                                    
> MaximumClique(Gr);
  {34, 1, 2, 12, 65, 66, 33 }
```